# How to create multiple views from a table column with a PostgreSQL trigger?

Tags: postgresql, loops, triggers, plpgsql

I work on a PostgreSQL database.

I'd like to use a loop to create multiples views from a table column.

Let's say I have this table `mylist` :

```
id  type  
1   Fish
2   Bird
3   Fish
4   Fish
5   Bird
```

I use that query to get all the distinct values from the type column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type from mylist;
```

It returns :

```
type
Fish
Bird
```

How could I use these two values in order to create automatically the following views (here I have only two values but in reality it's possible to get more than 50 distinct values):

- mylist_fish
- mylist_bird

I know that I should use a trigger but don't see how to create the views according to the values returned by my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to dynamically build and run all the creation statements.

You can do this at the command line, with the `\gexec` parameter.

```sql
SELECT
  FORMAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_table_view_%s AS SELECT * FROM myList WHERE type = %L',type,type)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM mylist) sub;\gexec
```

Run it first without the ending `\gexec` to see what will be executed. Using your sample, it would be:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_table_view_Fish AS SELECT * FROM myList WHERE type = 'Fish'
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_table_view_Bird AS SELECT * FROM myList WHERE type = 'Bird'
```

If you really need to put that inside a trigger or inside a function (though I personally wouldn't blindly create or recreate views on every table update), you can instead use `execute`. The example below uses an anonymous `do` block, you can move its content into your trigger.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT DISTINCT type FROM mylist 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_table_view_%s AS SELECT * FROM myList WHERE type = %L',row.type,row.type);            
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Just tried it and that works perfectly ! Thank you very much for your answer and your explanations !